# Tracking ip in etherscan

Tags: transactions, etherscan, hack

How do you find ip address in an ethereum transaction/etherscan?  My ledger wallet was recently compromised and the tokens in my wallet were stolen.   Is there anyway i can track the ip address in etherscan?   Whats the best recourse in trying to locate the thieves?

Comment: Were you ever able to recover your funds??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the IP address in an Etherscan transaction. IP addresses are not stored in the blockchain. Also, Ledger specifies that an IP address is only collected to be transmitted to their partners when this information is required to provide  services, and is not stored by Ledger.